# MVC FormCollection allKeys string [0]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, http-post, formcollection

Its my first time here, sorry if I wrote something wrong...

I have this HTML code, I need to get all the checkbox in a FormCollection

```
 [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult teste2(FormCollection collection)
            {
                var names = collection.AllKeys.Where(c => c.StartsWith("ckb") &&
                            collection.GetValue(c) != null &&
                            collection.GetValue(c).AttemptedValue == "1");

                return View();

            }
```

but I only get this result: allKeys string [0].
I tried do this using Ajax/Jason and other suggestions that I found on the web but I get the same result.
I have no ideia what's wrong.
Please, help me!  =]

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    <ul>
        @foreach (CWGD.BE.funcionalidade func0 in Model.func.Where(q => q.funcionalidade_pai == null))
        { 
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_@(func0.funcionalidade_id)"/>
                @func0.funcionalidade_nome
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var func1 in Model.func.Where(q => q.funcionalidade_pai == func0.funcionalidade_id))
                    {

                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_@(func1.funcionalidade_id)"/>
                            @func1.funcionalidade_nome
                            <ul>
                                @foreach (var func2 in Model.func.Where(q => q.funcionalidade_pai == func1.funcionalidade_id))
                                {

                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_@(func2.funcionalidade_id)" id="ckb_@(func2.funcionalidade_id)" />
                                        @func2.funcionalidade_nome</li>

                                }
                            </ul>
                        </li>                
                    }
                </ul>
            </li>        
        }
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Comment: What language would that be? Your tags are very generic.

Comment: Please do not tag such questions with the generic `mvc` tag but with `asp.net-mvc`. The MVC pattern exists not only in the ASP.NET environment, and only questions relating to the general MVC architecture should be tagged `mvc`, not issues with specific MVC implementations.

Comment: sorry! Now I know, i'll not do it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first job would be to launch [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) and see if the values are actually sent to the server. This is a generic advice that should be used every time any similar problem arises.

In your case the problem might be that your `<checkbox>` tags do not include `value` attribute so they will just send an empty value to the server.

Also you should provide the arguments to `Html.BeginForm` so that the form generates the correct target action.

Also remember that checkbox-es that are not checked, are never sent to the server in POST data.

Comment: "Also remember that checkbox-es that are not checked, are never sent to the server in POST data." That was the problem. It worked when checkbox was checked.  I'd like to get all checkboxes on server-side even the ones that was not checked. I'll think another way to do what i need =) Thanks a lot! Really helped!